# Как правильно скачивать файлы

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Собственно сабж. Пока тестировал локально, проблем не было. Пока стояло

```
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.78:8648/";
```

все замечательно скачивалось с локального сервера. Перенес на рабочий сервер

```
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://mysite.ru/";
```

получаю исключение `FileNotFoundException`, хотя файл есть и адрес, который он мне выдает, якобы не существующего файла - существует и в браузере открывается.

```
private void getImageFromURL(String path,String subDir, int i, int filesCount) throws IOException {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
        File file;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        InputStream inputStream;
        int totalSize;
        int downloadSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int bufferLength;

       //Для теста взял даже вот эту картинку (ну мало ли у меня что-то с серваком, но не помогло
        path = "http://yabs.yandex.ru/resource/SFCTnritCWB2pME4puotRQ.png";
        url = new URL(path);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        file = new File(MainConfig.getAlbumDir(subDir),fpPhoto);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();   //СОБСТВЕННО ТУТ И ВЫЛЕТАЕТ (

        totalSize = httpURLConnection.getContentLength();
        downloadSize = 0;
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadSize += bufferLength;
            publishProgress(downloadSize, totalSize, i + 1, filesCount);
        }
        fos.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Права на интернет в манифесте прописаны, но вот локально работает, а через интернет - нет

Ну и побочный вопрос, а как правильно скачивать файлы? может я вообще не в ту степь пошел. Нашел [на стоке ряд способов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog), но какой лучше способ заюзать? Этот взял как наиболее простой, на мой взгляд, для тестов. У меня есть база на сайте и она время от времени обновляется, поэтому приложение запрашивает новые данные. Данные парсятся ( `JSON` ) и, при необходимости, запрашиваются изображения/файлы и скачиваются на телефон. По ссылке я еще не ознакомился с реализацией всех методов, но может знающие люди, кто уже сталкивался с этим, подскажут верное решение.

**UPDATE:**
Спасибо за предложенные варианты возможных причин ошибки, общение всегда помогает найти ошибку, зачастую даже достаточно чтобы твой бред просто выслушали.

Я нашел ошибку свою. С какого-то перепуга я `setDoOutput` установил в true, в то время как он должен стоять в `false` в данном случае.  Теперь все работает. По второму вопросу все еще с радостью готов выслушать ваши пути решения задачи загрузки файлов.

Comment: Хороший вопрос (и особенно update). Очень познавательно. 

Казалось бы такая мелочь, и запрос [из GET превращается в POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect). 

А с другой стороны, чего еще ожидать от [такого уровня абстракции](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Рекомендую](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Comment: спасибо. Добавил в закладки, обязательно ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 0):

для загрузки/кеширования изображений советую воспользоваться [библиотекой](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) и не городить своих велосипедов.

Comment: Для отображения изображений ее и использую, но как писал выше, у меня помимо изображений есть еще и другие файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что вылетает потому что вы пытаетесь читать в UI потоке. В последних версиях Android это вызывает крэш системы.

Comment: Мой косяк - не привел полный код, он очень большой, но читается это в AsyncTask. И в задании написал, что с локального адреса - работает.